# How do I bind a MultiBinding on object-typed dependency property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, attached-properties

I have the following binding

```
<Display.Value>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
          <Binding Path="Nickname" />
          <Binding Path="FullName"  />
    </MultiBinding>
</Display.Value>
```

According to the [MultiBinding class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx), this is the correct syntax. However, when I bind it on a value property, only an empty string show up. This property works when I use SingleBinding or just a normal Binding, though.

```
public object Value
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(Display), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
```

However, when I bind my multibinding on another attached property (this time, the type is string)

```
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(Display), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
```

Any idea why multibinding does not work with `Value` but works with `Caption`? Is it because of the object type of Value? How can I make MultiBinding work with `Value`?

Comment: Those are not attached properties...

Comment: @H.B.what are they called? Sorry if it's wrong, feel free to edit the question,

Comment: [Dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). [Attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) are a special kind of dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

#### XAML

```
<Window ....
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - ({1})">
                    <Binding Path="Value.Nickname"/>
                    <Binding Path="Value.FullName"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Code-Behind

```
public class Value
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NicknameProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Nickname", typeof(string), typeof(Value), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Nickname
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NicknameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NicknameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FullNameProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("FullName", typeof(string), typeof(Value), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FullNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FullNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public Value()
    {
        Nickname = "Nickname";
        FullName = "FullName";
    }
}
```

So after the chat its best to use a Converter when dealing with non string. Using a StringFormat will work with strings.

Comment: in my case the nickaname and full name doesn't have dependency property, they are just classes with notify property changed events. Anyway, I was trying to bind it on my class' property (above), not on TextBox.Text

Comment: Can you reword your question so I know what you want

Comment: I was asking why MultiBinding doesn't work on Display.Value (object), but works on Display.Caption (string), and how to make it work on Value

Comment: It should. What are you multibinding to and how are you doing it

Comment: Right but what class contains FullName and Nickname

Comment: just a business class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` ... And I don't think it's relevant because if I change the StringFormat of the binding to stuff like "aadada" it still doesn't work with Value

Comment: Of course it matter. I cant give you a proper answer if your not telling me all the specs. Take a look at my code now

Comment: the reason why the solution doesn't apply is that you're binding to TextBox.Text, while I am binding to my own class, Display.Value. FullName and Nickname is not relevant, because, say, I can change the multibinding of <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})"> to <MultiBinding StringFormat="dadhasah"> and we can forget about FullName and Nickname and it still won't work

Comment: I'm so confused what you want....so that means your confused on what you want. What's a Display? What does it derive from? Rewrite your entire problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7484/discussion-between-mykullski-and-louis-rhys)

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiBinding` is aware of the type of the target property, if it is not of type `string` you should get this [binding error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx):

> System.Windows.Data Error: 31 : Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified. MultiBinding:'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding'

You could assign a `TextBlock` to `Value`, which has its `Text` bound via the `MultiBinding`, or you could of course employ a converter.